# Link stylesheet from another html

Tags: html, css, import

Hi there I would like to import a stylesheet import from another folder/ file when I put it on the other file and import it, it seems to have appear nothing...

folderpath:

```
app/css/stylesheeta.css

app/css/stylesheetb.css

app/css/stylesheetc.css

app/css/stylesheetd.css

app/module/module.js
```

app/lib/module/abc.js

In the html page,
app/views/stylsheet.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/stylesheeta.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/stylesheetb.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/stylesheetc.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/stylesheetd.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../module/module.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../lib/module/abc.css" />
```

In the main index.html

```
/index.html:
```

I include the stylesheet.html:

```
<head>
<link rel="import" href="app/views/stylsheet.html" />
</head>

<body>
   //some other stuff here
</body>
```

however there isn't any output of the stylesheet at all.. im wondering if what I do is permissable

Comment: Step1  : Does the app/views/stylsheet.html works properly with styles?

Comment: Did you try to add a `/`? like this: `"/app/views/stylesheet.html"`

Comment: Also test if the path to the stylesheet.html is correct and also the css files. Try adding some text to the html file to see if it shows up on your webpage

Comment: You have a spelling error in your question. You say that the links are in "app/views/stylesheet.html", however you refer to this page in your code as "app/views/stylsheet.html"

Comment: the path is correct I did print a hello world there but when I import the css style sheet it is wrong. are there better ways to import the parth?

Comment: @HarveyFletcher, nope that is in [link]index.html